# RewriteRule to capture whole search string produces empty result

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have the following rule in .htaccess:

`RewriteRule ^order(.*)$ /index.php?p=order&product=$1 [L,NC]`

It's a simplification because later on I want to add `order\?product=(.*)`

I access the website with:

`http://website.com/order?product=L0231-03868` but in the `$_GET` I'm only getting this:

`Array ( [p] => skonfiguruj-zamowienie [product] => )`

The `product` is empty. What am I missing?

-- edit
the moment I add the question mark

`RewriteRule ^order\?(.*)$ /index.php?p=order&product=$1 [L,NC]`

I get 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your URI doesn't really have anything after `order` so there is nothing to capture in `(.*)`.
- Use `QSA` flag to append original query string after rewrite.
- No need to repeat `order` on both sides.

Suggested rule:

```bash
RewriteRule ^(order)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Because of `QSA` flag, your original query string `product=L0231-03868` will be appended to `p=order` and you will get both parameters in php file.

---

Note about patter `^order\?(.*)$` generating `404`. Remember that a `?` will never be part of URI to be matched using `RewriteRule` hence this pattern containing a `?` is guaranteed to always fail.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples please try following htacces rules file. Make sure to keep your htaccess rules file along with index.php file, order folder(3 of them should reside inside root directory). Also clear cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(order)\?(product)=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^  index.php?p=%1&%2=%3 [QSA,L]
```

To make it more ***Generic***, as above rules are very samples specific only:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^?]*)\?([^=]*)=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^  index.php?p=%1&%2=%3 [QSA,L]
```

Documentation link:

[`%{THE_REQUEST}`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html) is being used here, which contains complete request line.

Comment: It's working. Why wouldn't normal RewriteRule work and I need to use the condition? Also I don't understand the `\s` in the Condition, or just the `^` in the Rule

Comment: @Moseleyi, yes we do need to use `THE_REQUEST` variable only here. Since that's the variable which contains actual request form(when link is hit) in itself. And for `\s` its value starts with it hence keeping it to do a match there.

Comment: @Moseleyi, I have added documentation link now for same and tried to explain it above comment also. Kindly do let me know in case of any further queries, cheers.